# Javascript - mapping mouse clicks over a grid

Tags: javascript, arrays, grid, mapping

I have a cube grid made of an array of arrays in javascript. The grid dimensions are stored in variables. So `dim` is the dimension of the single cube, `spacing` is the distance between each cube (`dim` and `spacing` expressed in pixels).

Now, considering that I can always have the user mouse position in the variables `g.mouseX` and `g.mouseY` why this code isn't always so precise?

```
var j = Math.round(g.mouseX / (dim+spacing));
var i = Math.round(g.mouseY / (dim+spacing));

// user clicked on the cell grid[j][i]
```

Sometimes I click a cube but it looks like he's considering the one nearby. It looks like the whole mapping of the user click is shifted of half a `dim`. Probably using Math.round makes everything almost wrong, but I don't see any other way to transform such a chaotic and unpredictable value as the user click to a precise coordinate in my grid.

Hope anyone can help on this!

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to truncate, not round. You can use `Math.floor`, which maps (e.g.) `3.7` to `3`:

```
var j = Math.floor(g.mouseX / (dim+spacing));
```

But really, why not just bind the `onclick` event of each grid cell?

Comment: will try this! Can't use onclick because these cells are not CSS or HTML elements. I'm drawing in a canvas so, from a browser perspective, these cells dont exists.